# How to get a @RemoteAction invoked ASAP in a Visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce, javascript-remoting

I have an Apex @RemoteAction that I want to invoke as early as possible as a Visualforce page loads. To this end I have placed the required JavaScript call at the beginning of the page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="AccountHierarchyController">
    <script>
    AccountHierarchyController.parents('{!Account.Id}', function(results, event) {
        ...
    }, {escape: false, buffer: false});
    </script>
    ...
</apex:page>
```

and confirmed that the call does execute early on in the page load.

However, it appears from evidence such as Chrome's "Network" view that the remote call (the first yellow bar named **apexremote** below) is delayed (but does occur before the DOMContentLoaded event).

Is there a way to get this call made earlier such as straight after the VFRemote.js has loaded?

[image]

Comment: With a remoting call i'm not sure, but this would run sooner if you could refactor it such that it was the `action` of the page, part of its constructor, or perhaps a getter/setter.

Comment: But is it really "substantially delayed"?  It looks like it is executing within 1.25 seconds and it has to at least come after VFRemote.js is loaded.  How much faster are you looking for?

Comment: I'd like it to have no cost e.g. to complete in parallel with say the 2014_winter_aloha.png load and be ready to use before the jQuery.ready - so about 0.7s earlier. Yeah I'll remove the word "substantially".

Comment: @KeithC shameless plug: [account hierarchy using javascript remoting](https://fflib-ext-common-developer-edition.na11.force.com/) - grab source code [here](https://github.com/financialforcedev/fflib-ext-common-samplecode)

Comment: @user320 Nice thanks for sharing this.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the VF page attributes to turn off the HTML and body tags, you can manually put them in the page and then get your remoting script up in the head tag instead of being in the body.

It's a little more markup, but probably will be higher in the page, depending on what else might be in the head.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting - didn't try that. The impression I get though is that the callout is blocked until some event within Salesforce's JavaScript (at 1.2 seconds in the image I attached) so am not optimistic and working on something else now. Also had to back off some of the aggressive JavaScript ordering to get it to work at all on IE7...

Answer (score 0):

@keithC

The delay is likely caused by a couple of scripts that SF injects onto all VF pages for performance monitoring. Try using ad blocker in your browser to block those urls, and you'll see a much snappier page response, including VisualForce Remoting callouts.

Comment: Which URLs are you talking about?